# Difference between a simplicial complex and a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

My mathematical sophistication is pretty low. Looking for an intuitive but accurate explanation of the different between a simplicial complex and a graph (a set of vertices and set of edges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph (unoriented) is a one-dimensional simplicial complex. More-dimensional simplicial complexes are sometimes referred to as "hypergraphs".